# UDP messages are sent faster than they are received

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, tkinter, udp

I've been working hours to send video frames through a UDP socket and this is what I've done so far:

Client side: sends the captured video and then receives it and rebuilds the frame and displays it on tkinter

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy
import threading


IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8080
my_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
my_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
root = Tk()
main_label = Label(root)
main_label.grid()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
LEN = 61440
DIV = 60


def send_msg(frame):
    for i in range(DIV):
        my_socket.sendto(frame[i*LEN:(i+1)*LEN], (IP, PORT))


def receive_msg():
    while True:
        data = b""
        while len(data) != (LEN * DIV):
            msg, add = my_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
            data += msg
        create_frame(data)


def create_frame(data):
    numpy_img = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    numpy_img = numpy_img.reshape(720, 1280, 4)
    img = Image.fromarray(numpy_img)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    main_label.configure(image=tk_img)
    main_label.tk_img = tk_img


def video_stream():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    colored_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    bytes_frame = colored_frame.tobytes()
    send_msg(bytes_frame)
    main_label.after(50, video_stream)


def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=receive_msg)
    t.start()
    video_stream()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Server side: sends everything it receives

```
import socket


IP = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8080
LEN = 61440


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
    while True:
        msg, add = server_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
        server_socket.sendto(msg, add)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the problem is that the video is displayed not like the regular video:

Regular:
[image]

Result:

[image]

as you can see, the parts of the frame itself are messy and I don't really know a possible way to fix it...

Comment: That's the point of UDP - no guaranteed delivery, no flow control. Simply don't use UDP if you need these or implement these in your application.

Comment: isn't udp better for video streaming though? or should I use tcp?

Comment: For real-time video UDP is better since in this case it is better to loose data than to have a high latency. For non-real-time video  TCP is better because here it is preferred to have a good quality and it is ok to buffer data.

Comment: got it. thank you very much!